# How do i replicate the HTML anchor tag navigation to Jump to a Specific Part of a Page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I am currently using `flutter_widget_from_html_core` to view html string that we got from our cms. Additionally, am using `url_launcher` package to open an anchor tag href.

Current approach:

```js
HtmlWidget(
  html ?? '',
  customStylesBuilder: (element) {
  },
  customWidgetBuilder: (element) {
  },
  onErrorBuilder: (context, element, error) {
  },
  onTapUrl: (url) async {
    return launchUrlString(url);
  },
)
```

How can i imitate the HTML's way of jumping to a specific part of a page based on the id of the element

something like in this example [here](https://codepen.io/cferdinandi/pen/LqGZrb)

Comment: Currently, the package you provided has no such feature. You can open issue on their repository. It would be great feature if they add this.

Answer (score 1):

In the `HtmlWidgetState` class, there is a method named `scrollToAnchor` which allows scrolling to a specific element identified by its `id`, see [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_widget_from_html_core/latest/flutter_widget_from_html_core/HtmlWidgetState/scrollToAnchor.html).

If you want to scroll as soon as the page is opened, you might consider initiating the scrolling action in the `initState` method. Here's how you could implement it:

```dart
class _MyState extends State<MyPage> {
  // a key for the state object that we need
  final GlobalKey<HtmlWidgetState> htmlWidget = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final String? target = widget.target;
    if (target != null) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        // wait until after the HTML content has been rendered
        // then request a scroll to the specified target
        htmlWidget.currentState?.scrollToAnchor(target);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView( // needed for long HTML
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: HtmlWidget(
            widget.html ?? '',
            key: htmlWidget, // needed to use `currentState` in our callback,
            onTapUrl: (url) async {
              return launchUrlString(url);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that there can be issues, especially if the HTML content is extensive. In such cases, the `HtmlWidget` might perform asynchronous rendering, which means immediate scrolling might not be feasible. However, this general approach should give you a good starting point.